# Google Pubsub PubsubMessage get ackid

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am following the example here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-java 
 However, I did not find a way to get ackid. I used to do `subscription.pull(1000)` in the older version (0.8.0) to get ReceivedMessage which has getAckId method, now I upgrade to 0.22.0-beta, I did not see how I can get ackid with PubsubMessage. Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new version of the client libraries, it is no longer necessary to get the ack ID. The documentation looks to be a little out of date and will need to be updated. The documentation on the [pull subscriber page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#pubsub-pull-messages-async-java) is correct. The `receiveMessage` method you override in your `MessageReceiver` implementation will be called with an `AckReplyConsumer` argument on which you can call `ack()`. This replaces the need to get the ack Id and then call the `Acknowledge` method.

Comment: How does one find ackids for the CLI client?  This cli does not accept message ids

gcloud pubsub lite-subscriptions  ack projects/foo/subscriptions/publisher-foo ack --ack-ids=[what goes here]